# Woocommerce How to make multiple product pages?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to Woocommerce.

I need to make product list pages for Windows, Android, and Accessories.
I already organized them by categories and made setting to display by "categories and subcategories."
However, in Shop page, still the products are showing. 
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

Also, how to make multiple category product pages?
For example, windows products page only need to show Windows products. And Android products page only need to show Android products.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

WooCommerce has default product category template and it has a default slug named 'product-category'.

So you can show different products by using the link likes:

http://yoursite.com/product-category/windows

http://yoursite.com/product-category/android

There are also some plugins that provide shortcodes/elements, so you can insert the shortcode or element on your page to show products for specific cateogry.

For example, if you are using WooCommerce with Visual Composer, there is a Product Categories element.

[image]

So you can insert the element with specific category setting on your page.

Answer (score 1):

First you should delete the shop page and make a page what you want to name. Also make a category with the same name. Then use this short code [products limit="8" columns="4" category="hoodies, tshirts" cat_operator="AND"] . In the place of hoodie and tshirt you specify your own category's slug name and that's it. And paste it in the page short code box. Now the page will only show one specific category product in a single page. You can also change products limit and number of products in a row.